# Отступ блока со списком

Tags: html, css

[**МАКЕТ** jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e1bLqu5w/)

Как сделать отступ у wrapper'а снизу и сверху, независимо от скроллинга?

Comment: Почему у wrapper'а не работает `overflow: hidden;`?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, тупой вопрос. Почему-то 2 дня не мог сделать, а сейчас дошло.

[Может, пригодится кому-нибудь](http://jsfiddle.net/e1bLqu5w/1/).